# How to install Canon printer/scanner drivers (deb.tar.gz file)?

Tags: software-installation, deb, canon, archive

I have a Canon MG2220 multifunction printer that I would like to use with Ubuntu 13.04 (which I just installed).  There are no print drivers available in the Ubuntu Software Center, so I downloaded some Linux drivers from Canon's Asia website.  They are:

- scangearmp-mg2200series-2.00-1-deb.tar.gz
- cnijfilter-mg2200series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz

I have found how to install ".tar.gz" files, but this one has ".tar.gz" in front of the ".deb", and I am concerned about doing anything that may screw up my system.

Can I use the same method for installing ".deb.tar.gz" as ".tar.gz" by following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030/47437) I found on Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just right-click the file and select "Extract here". That will give you a folder with a file named "something.deb". Double-click that file and you'll go to the Ubuntu Software Center where you can install it. Should be no need for any commandline stuff, unless you prefer to use commands rather than graphical tools.

Comment: I tried this and it did give me a .deb folder, but when I double-click on it it shows me two folders, "Packages", "Resources" and a file titled "Install.sh"  What do I do now?

Comment: I looked at the Install.sh file and it had a bunch of errors listed in it, but then I went into the "Packages" folder and found .deb files in it.  Should I click on the one that is specific to my printer?

Comment: That sounds about right, yes. Wonder why these companies can't find slightly more user friendly ways of doing things. :)

Comment: Well, I double-clicked on the other .deb files that I thought were related to my printer and OS (64-bit) and the printer printed a test page that came out wonderful with color and all!  Thanks again!  Dennis

Answer (score 3):

Here's what is going on:

A .tar.gz file is a compressed file, similar to a Windows .zip.  Some programs come as source code packed into a .tar.gz file, which you then use the instructions that you found for.

However, what you have is a .deb file, which installs a program on your computer without having to compile it.  This deb file is packed *inside* a .tar.gz (often referred to as a tarball), which means that you first uncompress it and then execute it with a program called `dpkg`.  Run the following commands:

```
tar -xzvf filename.deb.tar.gz filename.deb
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

Substitute "filename" for the name of your file *without* file extensions (hint: you can start typing in the name of an existing file and then press TAB to have the command prompt autocomplete it for you).  So, if you had a file named `blender.deb.tar.gz`, you would type the following:

```
tar -xzvf blender.deb.tar.gz blender.deb
sudo dpkg -i blender.deb
```

If you don't want to mess around with changing folders through the command prompt then just put the files in your home folder, and then run the above commands.

Comment: If the procedure that Jo-Erland Schinstad gave me above doesn't work, then I'll go with the terminal commands you mentioned above.  Thank you for your explanation.  I really needed that.  Boy have I got a lot to learn!

Comment: I got the printer to work using the graphical interface, but I appreciate your help.  I'll know how to uncompress tarballs and how to use dpkg in the future.  Sincerely, Dennis

Answer (score 2):

My printer is up and running.  I extracted the files by right mouse clicking on the .deb file folders and then I went into the folder titled "Packages" and double clicked on them and it opened up Ubuntu Software Center and I was able to install the drivers that way.  I appreciate everyone who helped me on this issue.  Sincerely, Dennis Primm

Comment: This is indeed the correct way to do it, Canon packaged the deb files in a very confusing way!

Answer (score 0):

After you extract the file it will just be a .deb file. Then you just type this in the command line:

`sudo dpkg -i foo.deb`

Where "foo.deb" is your file.

Comment: is that all there is to it?  I don't need to tell the computer where I extracted the file(s)?  I thought for sure there would be more to it than that.  I'll await your response.  Thank you!!!