# Printing canceled "Bond Types Inquiry Lab" on MG2200-series, whenever I try to print

Tags: printing, canon

I have a Canon MG2220 printer and am having trouble printing. When I try printing I get the message from Gnome 3, "Printing canceled "Bond Types Inquiry Lab" on MG2200-series".

I have completely setup the printer and installed the drivers according to this web page (and several others) "http://www.doopensource.com/hardware/making-a-canon-pixma-mg2220-print-from-linux/". I installed using the install.sh file and, after it still didn't work, using the two amd64 .deb files in the packages folder as stated on this webpage "[How to install Canon printer/scanner drivers (deb.tar.gz file)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344865/how-to-install-a-deb-tar-gz-file)", this did not work either. The printer is configured just fine in LibreOffice Writer and in the printer settings, but when I go to print a file, a little window pops up too quickly to read then I get the aforementioned message from Gnome.

Maybe I am just slow and unable to find anything, but I can't find anything on this issue. When I Google it or search it up on a forum or question site, it just brings up how to cancel printing. I am extremely frustrated and now hope that setting up a Windows 7 virtual machine will work, but I do not want to have to do this every time I print, as I will have start up the machine and to create a virtually shared folder and blah blah.

I was also able to get a really unclear screenshot of the window that pops up, in which some text is readable. I just am not quite sure how to post screens if someone could help me with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In frustration, I tried looking at the configuration available through the terminal command `sudo system-config-printer`. From there I right-clicked on "MG2200-series" and "Properties". I then noticed that in the "Make and Model" option was labeled "Gerneric text only printer".

I clicked on "Change..." next to the text and chose "Canon". After following and choosing the appropriate options, I clicked apply and all worked well.